# Determine the range of the function and whether it is one-to-one, onto, both or neither. Then, find all cases where $f(x) = x$

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

A. $f: \Bbb R\rightarrow \Bbb Z$, defined by the equation $f(x) =\lfloor x \rfloor$

B. $f: \Bbb N\rightarrow \Bbb N$, Where the least significant digit of $x$ is removed. For example, $f(13579) = 1357,\space f(619) = 61,\space f(4) = 0,\space f(0) = 0.$

---

**For A**, The function is *onto* as every number of the range will be matched with at least one number on the domain, but it isn't *one-to-one* because $f(2) = 2$ and $f(2.1) = 2$.

- The range of the function would be $ \Bbb Z$.
- As for the cases where $f(x) = x$, then $\forall x \in \Bbb Z$ such that $f(x) = x$

**For B,** Since every single digit number will equal $0$, the tens will equal $1$, twenties will equal $2$... etc
We can determine that the function is *onto* as every number in the range will be matched with at least one number in the domain, but the function isn't *one-to-one* because $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 0$

- The range of the function would be $\Bbb Z$.
- As for the cases, there's only one case: $x = 0$, $f(0) = 0$

---

This is the answer I ended up with. I am mainly uncertain when it comes to finding **all** cases where $f(x) = x$. A confirmation/feedback would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer for **A** is perfectly alright. Your answer for **B** however, has some mistakes that need to be addressed.

---

If $f: \Bbb N\to \Bbb N$, then any single digit natural number will not have an image in $\Bbb N$ ($0 \notin \Bbb N$) and thus the function cannot be defined $\Bbb N\to \Bbb N$. The correct co-domain, therefore must at least be $\Bbb N 
\space \cup \{0\}$.

Now, for $f: \Bbb N\to \Bbb N \space \cup \{0\} $, there is *no* $x$ that would satisfy $f(x)=x$. To understand why, simply note any number with more than $1$ significant digit will yield a number with $1$ lesser significant digit. These two numbers can obviously *not* be equal. The single digit numbers on the other hand, yield $0$ which does not even belong to the domain.

If you wish to include $0$ in your domain, you can define $f: \Bbb N \space \cup \{0\} \to \Bbb N \space \cup \{0\} $ which now yields $x=0$ as the only solution to $f(x)=x.$

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x)=x$,

$f:N\rightarrow N$ is one to one,
onto

$f:I \rightarrow R$ is one to one, into

$f:R \rightarrow I$ is not a not a map.

Here R is set of all real numbers, I is set of all integers, N is set of all natural numbers.